# Given an arc defined by a center point and start/end points, how do I calculate the length of the arc?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I.e. how do I calculate the length (? in the image below)?

[image]

Context: I'm responsible for a piece of software that parses AutoCAD files. These files can contain **a lot** of small arcs, most of which aren't needed in my application. They do however slow things down. I'd like to filter out "small" arcs, as defined by their length. By the time my application gets to filtering, the arcs have already been converted to the startpoint/endpoint/centerpoint format.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is exactly given? Coordinates of center, begin and end points? You can find radius as distance between center and begin point, and you can find cosine of angle from dot product of begin and point radius vectors. You should note that there are two arcs having the same center, begin and end points. That's why there are two possible values of angle (except case angle = $\pi$). Then you can use formula from answer. Note that this formula needs angle to be in radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the centre and a point on the circle then you know the radius.

When you know the endpoints of the arc then you know the angle in radians that is subtended by the arc sector.

Then you can calculate the arc length using the formula:

> arc length = radius $\times$ arc angle